# What is to "remove" like "prepend" is to "append"?

Tags: single-word-requests

**What is to "remove" like "prepend" is to "append"?**

In technical domains (e.g. programming), "append" adds something to the end, whereas "prepend" adds something to the beginning.

What is the analogue of "prepend" for "remove"?

Comment: Why do you think there would (or should) be such an analog (or analogue even), and what would it mean that is different from 'remove'?

Comment: Which end do you think "remove" applies to?

Comment: Need it only apply to an 'end'?

Comment: A sentence with context (using a blank for the word you want) would be helpful.

Comment: The equivalent of "append" might be "curtail".

Comment: In the culinary domain, we have top (and tail).

Comment: "remove" does not specify from where. You might want to use *pop-front* and *pop-back*.

Comment: ***Truncate*** always means ***remove** from the **end***, and in practice that's usually the implication of similar words like ***curtail, shorten, abbreviate, dock, trim,...*** But offhand I can't think of any specific "verb of removal" implying that something was removed from the ***front / top*** (apart from ***top*** itself, as applied to preparing root vegetables for cooking).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - In the Unix domain as well.

Comment: Two words normally used for a little off the top are "decapitate" and "prune."

Comment: @Chaim Might I suggest a different barber's?

Comment: @Chaim. I don’t get a sense of exclusively “off the top” in “prune”. Pruning roses is the archetype in my head and it involves cutting away sections all over the plant.

Comment: “Prepend” used like this seems to be a development from “append” (the traditional meaning of the verb was “ponder, consider”). Perhaps your only option here is to coin a word from something like “truncation” (“pre-truncation”?). *Yes, this is an appalling suggestion. I am joking!*

Comment: Well you were looking for pair-words for cutting at one end vs. cutting at the other. If I were uprooting a plant or cutting it at ground level I would not describe that action as "pruning."

Comment: In VB and other languages the function [Strings.Right()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right?view=netframework-4.8) effectively removes characters from the left(front) of the string.

Comment: I don't get it!!  How do you append or prepend with an analog computer???

Comment: I'd name the function _Cleave_ and let it take a number from 0 to 7 as an attribute ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't consensus in the domain.

In Javascript it's [**shift**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) for an array.  The equivalent in Swift is [**removeFirst**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2886730-removefirst). Swift's more explicit naming is likely due to the fact that *shift* is not intuitive.

Comment: In JavaScript we have *shift* and *pop* for an array, but no *remove*, perhaps because *splice* does both inserts and removals from the middle.